# How to use Supervised Generative Adversarial Network to inpaint images?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am currently trying to train a GAN to reconstruct / inpaint a set of images I have cropped.

Most papers I have found are about unsupervised or semi-supervised GAN, but in this case, I can use supervised training because my dataset contains ~20000 greyscale intact images with wire sections.

I have cropped from all the images a random triangle, and I intend to make the cropped set my inputs, while the original picture would be the outputs. I want to learn more about GAN networks, and that is why I do not use the OpenCV inpaint method. Can you suggest a good architecture or a good paper I can read about supervised GAN image inpainting? Thank you!